# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools and resources for the avid photographer
- techniques or tutorials for picture perfection
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/5007).

Comment: File size limit is now 150 KB: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273271/140933

Answer (score 2):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Upload to Wikimedia Commons, your pictures will help illustrate the free encyclopedia]

Comment: @SailorCire: The size is conform to the regulation: "*300 x 250 pixels, **or double** that if retina*"

Answer (score 1):

[image: Check out the Area 51 Remote Sensing Proposal]

Comment: Not really related to this site...

Comment: Lots of photographs taken from spaceborne and airborne platforms.  In fact, every photograph is a form of remote sensing.

Comment: [The chat room dedicated to this proposal](http://goo.gl/VxYdsL)

Comment: JoanneC: today [I saw that someone's added new example questions to the proposal](http://s1.picofile.com/file/8261086768/Capture.JPG), 4 of which are about camera calibration. spaceborne sensors are calibrated through dihedrals and tridedrals placed all over the world but I think remote sensing through airborne imagery and photogrammetry especially in case of close range (done even by common digital installed on drones or tripods) has a very close relationship with professional photography.

Comment: JoanneC: But if the scope of this site is only the art of photography, without regarding precision and accuracy, then I think you're right

Answer (score -1):

[image: Discuss the real world. Start Urban Planning SE!]

Comment: I'm going to see if I can get a dedicated ad soon that looks better than the... "not-so-bad" looking scheme of Area 51, but I've got exams right now, and I'm just trying to get ads across the network. :D

Comment: I'm missing the connection to photography here, I have to admit...

Comment: JoanneC: Yeah, I get that :/  I'll see if I can get an ad soon that's more custom for this site. I've got exams going on right now, but I'll try to get one hopefully by tomorrow :)